# How to prevent reset in a Struts form?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I have this struts form:

```
<s:form ...>
    <input id="foo" value="123"/>
</s:form>
```

I change the value of `foo` then I hit back button. When I come back , `foo` has lost my value and now is `123`.

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: you will have to submit the form on hitting the back button and store the values in session scope. Is it struts 1 or 2?

Comment: @ManuelM. It is Stuts-2

Comment: taka a look at this to process forms, i hope it helps. http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/processing-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

This is less of Strust's concern but more of browser's decision.

Check out the following related discussions:

[Browser back button restores empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261351/browser-back-button-restores-empty-fields)

[Clear Form on Back Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649747/clear-form-on-back-button) (doing the opposite)